# Plotting the gap between two times

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, survival, ggplot2

I have a (large) dataset where I know, for each observation, the departure and the arrival time of a worker (between 0 and 24, in decimal) :

```
ID      Departure_time    Arrival_time
0001    07.00             08.25
0002    07.55             08.20
0003    08.10             09.75
...     ...               ...
```

I can plot the density of the departure_time (or arrival_time) easily :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Departure_time)) + geom_density(adjust=.5)
```

I would like to plot the density of workers traveling for a given time (for each moment, the number of worker who are not at work (prior to arrival_time) but who have left home (after departure_time).

Comment: Do you want to know the number of workers en route at a given point in time, or the typical duration of a worker's commute?

Comment: The number of workers at a given time! I could get the typical duration with a subtraction: `mean(arrival_time-departure_time)`.

Comment: A loop over workers and a counter wich is incremented if departure < time < arrival will give you the number of workers travelling at a given time... Then loop on times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a vector called data

```
#Make this as fine as you want it. 
times<-seq(1,24,by=0.01)

d<-sapply(times,function(x){
  sum(data[,2]<=x & data[,3]>=x)
 })

hist(d)
```